# Как получить данные из связаной модели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Мне на главную страницу сайта необходимо выводить список товаров. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как вывести фотографию товара. Вот мои модели:

```
class Product(models.Model):
...
```

И есть модель в которой храняться фотографии товара

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')
...
```

Вот код из view.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    template = 'shop/product/list.html'
    products = Product.objects.all
    ....
    return render(request, ... 'products': products, ...)
```

Вот шаблон:

```
{% for product in products %}
...
<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ ???? }}"></a>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Вопрос :  Как получить queryset фотографии товара, чтобы вывести их на странице списка товаров.(Рандомную или первую каждого товара)

Answer (score 1):

Получить доступ к записям, связанным отношением `ForeignKey` с текущей, можно следующим образом:

```py
product.productimage_set
```

Получить первую запись из `QuerySet` можно методом `first`.

***Пример:***

```py
<img src="{{ product.productimage_set.first.image.url }}">
```

---

***P. S.:*** Почему бы не изменить модели так?:

```py
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')


class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage, models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Спасибо, делал и раньше так как вы предложили, но почему-то отображалась только какая-то иконка изображения. Для того что-бы полноценно все работало, необходимо а конец добавить _.url_ . А касаемо моделей то у меня именно так, как вы и описали вышею Спасибо